# React/Webpack Publishing to npm

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, reactjs, npm, webpack, browserify

I have a component that I've built using webpack and gulp to manage and build. It's all done and ready to be published.

How do I only publish the build `public/*` directory for consumption by other apps?

Currently the build works fine and I'm committing/pushing everything to GitHub, but the publish to npm really only needs the `bundle.js` and `main.css` files, correct?

How would I do this? Currently npm publish is pushing everything up and then using `<variable> = require('<package>')`is giving me the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '<package>' from '/Users/<username>/Apps/<project>/app/assets/javascripts'
```

This is a rail project that we're using browserify to handle allowing `require(...)` and is working for other npm packages.

What am I missing?

Comment: after publishing to npm, did you make sure it's available on npmjs.com ? did you install the package locally into your project before require-ing it ? npm install --save myPackageNameThatIsAvailableOnNpmJs.com

Comment: it's actually a private package for my company and I did `npm install <package> --save`. Looking in the _node_modules_ directory I see the package and it has everything, dev code and built _bundle.js_ but the project still can't find it

Comment: how about if you explicitly require it ? like `require('./node_modules/package_name/index.js')` ? does it work in that case ?